# What is the difference between "whereabout" and "whereabouts"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between "**whereabout**" and "**whereabouts**"

I have heard both of them, but don't know the difference...

I would appreciate a lot the help.

Comment: If there were only one whereabout then you wouldn't be wondering as to the whereabouts of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Where( )about(s)* is a local variant on *where* as  used in a question.
It means 'give me some idea of the general vicinity'

- *Whereabout were you when you realized you didn't have your phone?*

Some would say *whereabouts*. There's no difference, but both are stressed on the **last** syllable.

The other *whereabouts* (always with -*s*) is a noun. It refers to someone's present location, and the person is indicated by a possessive:

- *Bill's whereabouts is/are unknown.* (some say it's plural, others don't)

**This** *whereabouts* is stressed on the **first** syllable, not the last.

Executive summary: *WhereabOUT were you?* versus *His WHEREabouts*.